# Adding a sound button using Swift in Xcode

Tags: swift

i am having trouble adding a sound in swift, currently the sound works fine but it begins to play as soon as the app opens instead of when i press the button

```
 import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var alertSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("SoundP", ofType: "mp3")!)
        println(alertSound)

        // Removed deprecated use of AVAudioSessionDelegate protocol
        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: nil)
        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, error: nil)

        var error:NSError?
        audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: alertSound, error: &error)
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        audioPlayer.play()
    }

}
```

So that is the code and every time i try to add a IBAction it says that "only instance methods can be declared as IBActions.

The name of the button i want it to be added to is called TapandRead and the sound being played is called SoundP and its a mp3

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare it using an `IBAction` connection. `IBAction`s should be declared inside your class but outside the other methods of the class. Make sure you connect the `UIButton` to the `IBAction` property.

```
@IBAction func TapandRead(sender: AnyObject) {
 var alertSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("SoundP", ofType: "mp3")!)
    println(alertSound)

    // Removed deprecated use of AVAudioSessionDelegate protocol
    AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: nil)
    AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, error: nil)

    var error:NSError?
    audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: alertSound, error: &error)
    audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    audioPlayer.play()
}
```